# Why does an Express function take both the Request and Response as arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I am new to node.js and am acquainting myself with Express. The following code is my source of confusion:

```
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

function handleRequest(req, res) {
  var path = req.url;

  switch (path) {
  case "/n":
    return renderPage_1(req, res);
  default:
    return renderPage_2(req, res);
  }
}
```

I understand that the server needs to accept an HTTP request(req). However, if we are returning a response, why is the response also an argument in the callback function? I keep running into a dead-end thinking that it has to do with the scope of the response object, though I am not sure.

I would greatly appreciate clarification on this matter. I have not been able to find a resource that delineates my confusion.

Best,
Abid

Comment: because you aren't returning the response... returning does nothing other than terminate the function in this case.

Comment: See the documentation.

Comment: @KevinB In this case, the switch statement returns the result of renderPage_1(req,res). I do not understand how it is doing nothing besides terminating the function, because otherwise it defaults to  renderPage_2(req,res).  Overall my code works, I understand how to write it such that it works, but I dont know whats going on beneath the hood, sorry if that was not clear enough in the original question.

Comment: it terminates the function, thus preventing the default case from occuring. A break would have done that too. The return could have even been on a separate line returning nothing.

Comment: @KevinB Yes thats true and it makes sense to me. But Im confused as to why there are both request and response parameters used in these callback functions if the server is listening for requests only. Hope my confusion is clearer now.

Comment: The response param contains an object you can use to build/send the response. that is it's purpose. Without it, you couldn't respond to the client.

Comment: Basic request handling usually means you call `res.send(reply)` or `res.render(view, params)`. It's how express is built.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to your question is that this is how the authors of express decided to implement the library. At a high level, express is really just a light-ish weight wrapper that makes it easy to build middleware based http services with NodeJS. The reason that both the req & res objects are passed to each express middleware function is that in practice, web services are rarely able to fulfill an entire request in a single step. Often services are built as layer of middleware the build up a response in multiple steps.

For example, you might have a middleware function that looks for identity information in the request and fetches any relevant identity metadata while setting some auth specific headers on the response. The request might then flow to an authorization middleware that uses the fetched metadata to determine if the current user is authorized and if the user is not authorized can end the request early by closing the response stream. If the user is authorized then the request will continue to the next piece of middleware etc. To make this work, each middleware function (step of the stack) needs to be able to access information from the request as well as write information to the response. Express handles this by passing the request and response objects as arguments to the middleware function but this is just one way to do it.

Now the authors could have decided to implement the library differently such that each route handler was supposed to return an object such as `{ status: 200, content: "Hello, world" }` instead of calling methods on the response object but this would be a matter of convention and you could pretty easily write a wrapper around express that let you write your services like this if you wanted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps so much actually! Precisely the insight on Express that I was looking for!